# Create a pivot table with a column for each assignee, containing rows of task descriptions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a two-column table with the first column being "task description" and second column being "assignee". This is something I'm unable to influence.

Crude representation:

[image]

I'd like to be able to create a pivot table in a different sheet with a unique column for each assignee, containing rows of task descriptions assigned to that person.

What I'd also like to do is having each cell in this table to actually be a `=HYPERLINK(...)` to the corresponding task description cell in the original sheet. This is something, as I understand, that is impossible with built-in pivot tables. I've tried constructing a pivot table with those specifications and succeeded, but the links were not clickable.

[image]

"HYPERLINK" column formula is

`=HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=A" & MATCH(Task, Tasks!A1:A, 0), Task)`

---

Is it possible to accomplish this?

I've fiddled around with `=QUERY(...)` with mixed success as I've been unable to automatically generate columns for the table. What I have so far is query that generates headers for the table, and a query that generates rows for that header, but I have to manually copy and paste the second query - it's not automatically applied to ALL columns. For example, I've added a new task for "Purple" and corresponding tasks are not listed automatically.

[This is an example of what I'd like to do](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Md_niY1nrOPtOOv3TseLl-ftRUH5Vpr6OzPizM56-GE/edit?usp=sharing). This is the closest I've gotten to the solution but still not quite right.

---

## UPDATE

I've managed to avoid using `=QUERY` completely, and switched to `=ARRAYFORMULA` with `=FILTER` and `{;}` syntax.

[image]

All that is left with this approach, is to *skip* empty cells in columns. This is something I have no idea how to handle.

If anyone could chime in, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Hey, can you share a dummy sheet ? or a screenshot with some data + expected result. Maybe a `=query` + pivot or a combination of `=unique`, `=transpose` and `=filter`

Comment: @pjmg I've edited my question with a link to the example sheet, thanks!

Comment: It looks that you already managed how to get result that you was looking for on the Pivot(Query) sheet. Right?

Comment: Well no, because I'd like to avoid having to manually expand the formula across the columns. In Pivot(Query) when new assignees appear, I have to copy and paste the formula into a new column. I've added a new assignee - "Purple" and tasks assigned to purple are not shown in Pivot(Query). In Pivot(af+f), tasks are shown but with a lot of empty space between.

Comment: @PuzomorCroatia Please update the question.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question with new screenshots. Did you have something else in mind maybe?

Comment: @PuzomorCroatia Actually, it will more helpful that you add to the question a description of the spreadsheet content and why each "solutions" included don't work for you. Regarding the images, I suggest you to remove the blank columns to the right as they doesn't provide any useful information.